Hotel asks me to cancel due to room being double-booked, months after booking
I just got this message on Expedia from my hotel, months after I have booked my stay in Sweden:

Dear [name], We sincerely apologize for the inconvenience caused by an error in our system, which has unfortunately resulted in your room being double-booked. We completely understand your frustration, and we deeply regret that we are unable to host you on this occasion. As a gesture, we would like to offer you a 15% discount on your next stay with us. We hope to welcome you in the future and provide you with a more enjoyable experience. In the meantime, we kindly ask you to cancel your booking. Rest assured, you will receive a 100% refund for the inconvenience caused. Once again, we are truly sorry for this situation and thank you for your understanding. Please feel free to call us if you have any questions. Best Regards, [Hotel]

It feels rather weird that they are asking me to cancel, instead of them doing it themselves.
What should I do? Am I entitled to still getting a room?

There are probably penalties for them - either in financial terms or in terms of listing priority if they cancel. I'd also check very carefully if you have a fully refundable booking or not.

Is your booking during a (very) busy period such as a large exhibition, convention, concert, etc? Are there still suitable alternative accommodations available, at decent prices? Is your specific hotel still showing availability? Some hotels forget to set higher prices for these high-demand periods enough in advance, and when they realise, they have a tendency to cancel existing "cheap" bookings so they can resell the same room at a higher price.

"Months after booking": I suspect jcaron reasons (but if it is a very small hotel with limited "electronic" capabilities of staff, AND open only seasonally. Call and ask, but 15% is IMHO too low.

You booked via Expedia. Consider getting in touch with their customer support, as this might be against their terms.

In addition to the advice and warning in the other comments and in the answer, is the hotel part of a large chain? If so (taking well into account the advice given), you could try to get a credit/voucher valid for the whole chain or points on their loyalty program. It could be more useful than a discount on a hotel you may never visit again. Make sure you pay attention to the validity of such vouchers/credits/points though, they will probably range anywhere between 90 days and a year…

I believe there is little chance of finding similar accomodtion for same dates and for similar rates. Check you agreement with the hotel, see if they are liable to provide you with alternate accomodation on similar rates. Do not cancel in any case. This explains why they would like you to cancel

I suggest pushing the problem to Expedia, if for no other reason than that Expedia can potentially offer you something you might actually want (an Expedia voucher or discount, which is much more useful than anything the hotel can offer). Of course the hotel does not want that, but that's really not your problem.

@SalmanArshad That specific partner-initiated cancellation policy page applies to "vacation rentals booked on Vrbo" rather than hotels. But there's probably something similar for hotels. And even if there are no fees, there could be other impacts (change to the rating shown, change to the priority in listings, delisting if they exceed a cancellation threshold...).

@jcaron correct about VRBO. And yes, their contract with partners (not generally published online) does require them to reloacate the guest to identical accomodation and cover the cost of transportation. If Expedia gets involved, the hotel pays to Expedia for the said arrangements.

Also, in case they're trying to sell the same room at a higher price, check if you (or someone else) can still book rooms with them electronically via Expedia on the day in question

If it's a chain hotel, the chain has policies that the franchisee is supposed to follow with alternate accommodation and potentially cash compensation. You can call the chain's customer service number and bring it up with them.

Why they are asking you to cancel? Obviously to avoid any penalties from Expedia. Expedia surely does not like the hotels to unilateraly cancel, so the hotel tries to make it look that you have cancelled yourself.
Why did this happen? We could not know, only guess. This may be as simple as a human mistake, especially if the hotel is small. Maybe, as @jcaron has pointed out, the hotel wants to resell your room at a higher price. Maybe they had some fault in the room, e.g. a severe leak that severly damaged a few rooms...
I see basically three options of what you can do.
Firstly, you can accept the offer as is. Personally for me 15% discount on a future visit sounds too low, but maybe you can still rebook in another hotel at a similar price, and maybe you are anyway going to the same city soon, and really liked this hotel to book with them once again... In any case, triple-check that if you cancel you will get all the money back. The hotel will probably gladly waive any cancellation fees, but Expedia might not.
Secondly, you can try to negotiate a better offer. Maybe you can get 30% discount on a future stay. Maybe they can offer you free upgrade for this stay. Maybe you will be able to get them book you another hotel nearby... Once again, before you end up cancelling the booking, triple-check that you will get full refund.
And finally, and this is what I would do, you can immediately contact Expedia support. Most probably they have some process to handle such situations, and will either make a hotel reconsider their decision (maybe the hotel will find another customer willing to cancel), or find another accomodation for you. I had a similar situation with booking.com (see What is the typical booking.com compensation policy in case accomodation was cancelled by host?), and I must admit that they did not resolve the situation to my satisfaction, but I got at least something.
Also if you have any travel insurance, check their terms and probably contact them.

In fact, the hotel may even be violating Expedia terms simply by asking you to cancel (and maybe even you will be violating — I have not read Expedia ToC, but it may contain a clause that a customer should not cancel a booking on a request from a hotel), so continuing talks with the hotel may be shady… If they have contacted you via Expedia (not via Whatsapp or Viber etc) — this is good, because Expedia support will be able to see the communication. Do not talk to the hotel via any other channels, redirect all contact attempts back to Expedia — unless you are really going to agree to their offer.
Also I do not think that any agreement you reach with the hotel will be enforceable — e.g. if you agree for a 15% discount, and then try to use it on a month long stay, the hotel can easily back up from the agreement (you can ask at Law.SE for a better analysis, but would you sue them anyway?). So I do not recommend accepting the offer unless you have a clear plan for a future trip, and discuss this plan with them in advance. That is, do not get "15% for any future booking", but "15% for an upcoming trip from 3 to 10 March 2025 for one double standard room".

I would assume that finding a room for the original booked time period somewhere else  in the city would be much more useful to OP than getting their money back. If they can't host OP they should find an alternative (and provide some compensation on top for the inconvenience like the 15% off coupon).

Hotels overbook, it is pretty much normal. And yes, expedia tracks cancelled by guest and cancelled by owner separately.

It did happen to me that a hotel asked me to cancel, and it was in a busy week with a huge festival in the town with no chance of finding any other reasonable accommodation. They tried to present it as "how things are done", and I said that if they book me another room in another hotel in a similar price range and location, I will be glad to cancel. They did just that, pulled some strings, used personal connections, and did find me a room at competitors close by. Something which I could not have likely been able to do on my own. Who is doing the canceling is this important for them.

@quarague, @ vsz, thanks, I've slightly updated my option two to include possibility that the original hotel will book another room

15% off a price, which the hotel can decide? Hm... No, that is indeed laughable: a tiny reduction from a hotel whose management you cannot trust. That's not quite AirBnB-level of mismanagement, where I've had rooms cancelled while I was on my transatlantic flight there, but it's bad.
